# Android - Setting for Tablets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resolution

I am pretty new to Android. I wanted to know that if i want to design a tablet application then what changes i want make in the existing code which i designed for normal phone.

I did the Research and found,

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

and in Manifest

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Is it all done?? or I want to change something other than this??

Comment: then do googling brother

Comment: after googling i found this bro..i stuck in where to put xml files.. means in which folder for a particular resolution..

Comment: just follow the link of given by Brontok. it's give u right direction.ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new layout files for tablet versions, Java part is enough but layouts and image drawables are the main things you need.

Go through [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts), Here you will have a complete idea about how to create UI supporting Tablets and their **res** folders.

For all tablet resolutions check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices#Tablet_computers)

below are the available resolutions for android mobile and tablet

```
1   2560*1600
2   1366*768
3   1280*800
4   1280*768
5   1024*768
6   1024*600
7   960*640
8   960*540
9   854*480
10  800*600
11  800*480
12  800*400
13  640*360
14  640*240
15  480*320
16  400*240
17  320*240
```

Most Common tablet resolutions are

```
Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 3G - 10.1 inches, 1280 x 800 pixels
Samsung P1000 Galaxy Tab - 7.0 inches, 600 x 1024 pixels
```

Comment: sorry to ask you..actually i jumbled.. u said that i need to recreate layout xml files.. so, my problem is what changes i need to make in existing layout xml files??

Comment: and i don't have images of different sizes.. so can't i keep that in drawable folder..so that it will support all the devices..??

Comment: See if you don't have different images you need to hardcode the height and width of your image resulting in distorting image as image will get pixelated and will not be clearer because density of tab is also changed, Think it like this way you are extending a rubber , the actually symmetry of image will get disturbed if you use the same image on some bigger resolution phone.

Comment: If you keep the same drawables either you have to use 9 patch bitmap  that are re-sizeable or you have to compromise with the quality of images that will be seen on tablets.

Comment: fix height and width of views

Comment: ok.. thank you.. if i am hardcoding the image size then what is standard size for tablet..

Answer (score 0):

For application to be worked, this is enough. But you should take care the size of the application When you are adding images to drawable folders it will increase your project size. So if you are using same images for all screens put that image in drawable folder. It will pick automatically to all screens, and if you want different image for different screen size put in different layout folders. You can make different layouts according to screen size to be fitted. The android will automatically pickup the proper xml files.

Comment: it will pick automatically

Answer (score 0):

add `layout-large-hdpi` folder to ur resources and copy the files from `layout` to created one,
all ur created layouts will automatically converted to tablet screen size