# Want to Provide layout for 21 inch screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I just want a layout folder for 21 inch screen.I have sw600dp for 7 inch tablet and sw720dp layout folder for 10 inch tablet.how i specify folder for hp slate 21 inch tablet in android?thanks in advance

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316888/android-setting-for-tablets

Comment: @android_beginner: i know the display screen size 1920 x 1280 pixel so what will be name of layout folder should i use?

Comment: Check this link : http://developer.android.com/training/tv/index.html
just out of curiosity, can u share a link to see 21 inch tablet.?

Comment: @santosh:http://h20435.www2.hp.com/t5/The-Next-Bench-Blog/Slate21-Android-Lands-on-One-Awesome-All-in-One/ba-p/81757 this is link

Comment: Hi, Have you found how to do it?

Comment: @SharadMhaske. Have you found the solution.

Comment: @BalajiDhanasekar.nope1

Comment: @SharadMhaske. Am trying a lot for this. I don't know what layout and drawable to use and how to test it. Do  you have any suggestions. Please comment.

Comment: you can do one thing.have your 21inch layouts in default layout folder and need to calculate the screen size in inch then set the layout from default layout folder for that you need to have diff name for layout files so that it will pick it from default layout folder.

Comment: or use layout_weight for layout so that it will adjust according to size so that you dont need to give different layout folder.hope this helps you. have a try.

Comment: Yes Exactly. I too tried the layout_weight and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the resolution (or roughly) of the screen you can work out the dp folder you'll need.

```
px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

Comment: i got this display of devices so 1920 by 1080 pixel so what will be the name of layout folder?

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html .
sw720dp means smallest width 720dp, so this will be used by all devices having a smallest width of 720dp **or more**.

Comment: i dont want sw720dp for 21 inch tablet

Comment: sw720dp does not mean you get a layout thats 720dp wide. Layouts in Android always adopt to the available screen size. It's just that you can provide a different layout here for large screens and provide another one for handheld devices in the default layout folder.

Comment: so how i provide layout for 21 inch screen?

Comment: By putting the layout in the layout-sw720dp folder.

Comment: i have layout folder layout-sw720 for 10 inch tablet as i have very big layout for 21 inch screen which may not look good on 10  inch screen.

Comment: You don't get it, do you? Android stretches each layout so it fills the available space. You can run the same app with the same layout on a 3.5'' screen as well as on a 21'' screen and it will always fill up all the screen space. The different layout-<xy> folders are only there if you want to provide a separate layout, e.g. with two columns instead of one, for larger screens.

Comment: what about the dimensions of diff view?i dont want same dimension on 21 inch screen.i know layout will streches but i dont want that right?

Comment: Well, you can go with a layout-w1024dp and replace the 1024 by the dp-value of the 21'' screen. To calculate that value you'll need the device's resolution as well as the size. According to the link you posted, the device has a resolution of 1920 by 1080 pixels on a 21.5'' 16:9 screen. This means it has a width of 18.73'' which gives us a resolution of (only) 102dpi, and thus, according to http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html would use the layout-ldpi!

Comment: :their is nothing like layout-w1024dp as it gives error.i think google has not specified the layout folder for 21 inch screen specifically.

Comment: @Ridcully. I too have the same problem. Could you please provide me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below code in somewhere your `Activity` and run the application in that device, you will get the value of smallestWidthDp.
suppose if you get it 800 then you need to create layout folder named `layout-sw800dp`

```
Configuration mConfig = this.getResources().getConfiguration();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
        int smallest_width_dp_value = mConfig.smallestScreenWidthDp;
                    Log.e("smallestWidthDp",smallest_width_dp_value+"");
    }
```

Comment: i dont have that device for testing that is the pbm i m facing.its hp slate 21 tablet