# How to set layout and drawable on 21 inch tablet?

Tags: android, layout

I just want a layout folder for 21 inch screen.I have sw600dp for 7 inch tablet and sw720dp layout folder for 10 inch tablet.how i specify folder for hp slate 21 inch tablet in android?
thanks in advance.

Comment: A very nice SO post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403794/want-to-provide-layout-for-21-inch-screen-in-android) talking about layout for 21 inch screen in android

Comment: Thanks for your quick response,the below code i need to put in onCreate ? using this we get layout from layout-sw800dp ? and same as i need to create folder for drawable right ?                                                       Configuration mConfig = this.getResources().getConfiguration();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
        int smallest_width_dp_value = mConfig.smallestScreenWidthDp;
                    Log.e("smallestWidthDp",smallest_width_dp_value+"");
    }